# BootstrapVue - `multiple` Attribute of the Form File Input not Working

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

When I followed teh BootstrapVue doc to do the Form File Input, I used `multiple` attribute.
However, still only one file can be selected.
My code is just the same as the doc which is

> **<template>**

```
<b-form-file
      placeholder="Choose a file..."
      drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
      multiple
      v-model="files"
    ></b-form-file>
```

> **<script>**

```
data() {
      return {
        files: []
      }
```

##### Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you selecting multiple files?
Are you clicking on the input, selecting a single file and then opening it again to select another?

Comment: Using the provided sample I was able to select multiple files so I suspect the same, possibly looking for a different behavior than what's built in.

Comment: @Hiws Yes exactly, I wonder whether it is the correct way?

Comment: @Tim It's a bit weird, could you plz tell me how you select them? I just do as Hiws said, but as I choose the second file, the first one is then replaced by the 2nd.

Comment: @hcww `I wonder whether it is the correct way?`. No that is not the correct way. The `mulitple` prop allows you to choose multiple files *at once*. Meaning you open the window and select *multiple* files, and then press OK.